# How to restructure Nested JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I Am using Javascript to fetch JSON in this format:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "serialNumber": "12345678",
        "loopCount": 2,
        "temperature3": 22.74921781259558,
        "temperature2": 21.459065450414467,
        "temperature1": 25.60573959350586,
        "temperature7": 20.560272859443444,
        "temperature6": 24.672770566493245,
        "temperature5": 21.418451432003607,
        "temperature4": 24.136719323883636,
        "temperature8": 23.106006457744044
    },
    "deviceID": "12345678",
    "timestamp": "1514876959940"
}, {
    "data": {
        "loopCount": 3008,
        "serialNumber": "12345678",
        "temperature3": 24.340541769172475,
        "temperature2": 24.592980449259386,
        "temperature1": 25.208276748657227,
        "temperature7": 22.95620713734396,
        "temperature6": 24.173083663793975,
        "temperature5": 22.274865355495226,
        "temperature4": 23.507075904805543,
        "temperature8": 20.596809083024773
    },
    "deviceID": "12345678",
    "timestamp": "1514910791413"
}]
```

I would like to restructure the JSON object Using Javascript to look like this:

```
[{
    "loopCount": 3009,
    "serialNumber": "12345678",
    "temperature3": 20.938793894509594,
    "temperature2": 20.631314982104072,
    "temperature1": 25.192977905273438,
    "temperature7": 21.514532309261064,
    "temperature6": 24.03336173424463,
    "temperature5": 23.453609565992643,
    "temperature4": 24.424291668247513,
    "temperature8": 22.044323519108403,
    "timestamp": "1514910802296"
}, {
    "loopCount": 3009,
    "serialNumber": "12345678",
    "temperature3": 20.938793894509594,
    "temperature2": 20.631314982104072,
    "temperature1": 25.192977905273438,
    "temperature7": 21.514532309261064,
    "temperature6": 24.03336173424463,
    "temperature5": 23.453609565992643,
    "temperature4": 24.424291668247513,
    "temperature8": 22.044323519108403,
    "timestamp": "1514910802296"
}]
```

Currently, this is what I have:

```js
  var myObj =[{
 "data": {
  "serialNumber": "12345678",
  "loopCount": 2,
  "temperature3": 22.74921781259558,
  "temperature2": 21.459065450414467,
  "temperature1": 25.60573959350586,
  "temperature7": 20.560272859443444,
  "temperature6": 24.672770566493245,
  "temperature5": 21.418451432003607,
  "temperature4": 24.136719323883636,
  "temperature8": 23.106006457744044
 },
 "deviceID": "12345678",
 "timestamp": "1514876959940"
},  {
 "data": {
  "loopCount": 3008,
  "serialNumber": "12345678",
  "temperature3": 24.340541769172475,
  "temperature2": 24.592980449259386,
  "temperature1": 25.208276748657227,
  "temperature7": 22.95620713734396,
  "temperature6": 24.173083663793975,
  "temperature5": 22.274865355495226,
  "temperature4": 23.507075904805543,
  "temperature8": 20.596809083024773
 },
 "deviceID": "12345678",
 "timestamp": "1514910791413"
}, {
 "data": {
  "loopCount": 3009,
  "serialNumber": "12345678",
  "temperature3": 20.938793894509594,
  "temperature2": 20.631314982104072,
  "temperature1": 25.192977905273438,
  "temperature7": 21.514532309261064,
  "temperature6": 24.03336173424463,
  "temperature5": 23.453609565992643,
  "temperature4": 24.424291668247513,
  "temperature8": 22.044323519108403
 },
 "deviceID": "12345678",
 "timestamp": "1514910802296"
},  {
 "data": {
  "loopCount": 3462,
  "serialNumber": "12345678",
  "temperature3": 20.927366751292798,
  "temperature2": 23.690258459678994,
  "temperature1": 24.851139068603516,
  "temperature7": 22.797037129771063,
  "temperature6": 24.46046332152272,
  "temperature5": 24.415112076761666,
  "temperature4": 21.217672372617155,
  "temperature8": 20.609864963787967
 },
 "deviceID": "12345678",
 "timestamp": "1514915728668"
}]





for (var key in myObj) {
 //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj.length + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.serialNumber + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.loopCount + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].timestamp + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature1 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature2 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature3 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature4 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature5 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature6 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature7 + "<br>";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[key].data.temperature8 + "<br> <br>";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>How to access nested JSON objects.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to map that array or render it as HTML?

Comment: Why do you need to change the structure? You seem to be having no problems accessing the information in its current format.

Answer (score 0):

With ES7 you could use map and spread:

```
data.map(x => ({ ...x.data, timestamp: x.timestamp }))
```

ES6 Without the spread:

```
data.map(x => Object.assign({}, x.data, { timestamp: x.timestamp }))
```

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to restructure the JSON object Using Javascript to look like this.

You can use the function `map`.

```js
var array = [{    "data": {        "serialNumber": "12345678",        "loopCount": 2,        "temperature3": 22.74921781259558,        "temperature2": 21.459065450414467,        "temperature1": 25.60573959350586,        "temperature7": 20.560272859443444,        "temperature6": 24.672770566493245,        "temperature5": 21.418451432003607,        "temperature4": 24.136719323883636,        "temperature8": 23.106006457744044    },    "deviceID": "12345678",    "timestamp": "1514876959940"}, {    "data": {        "loopCount": 3008,        "serialNumber": "12345678",        "temperature3": 24.340541769172475,        "temperature2": 24.592980449259386,        "temperature1": 25.208276748657227,        "temperature7": 22.95620713734396,        "temperature6": 24.173083663793975,        "temperature5": 22.274865355495226,        "temperature4": 23.507075904805543,        "temperature8": 20.596809083024773    },    "deviceID": "12345678",    "timestamp": "1514910791413"}];

var result = array.map((o) => ({...o.data, timestamp: o.timestamp}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```